# Turbo Charging Suzuki Splash/Ritz

Tags: engine, suzuki, turbocharger

Can I turbo charge my Suzuki Splash/Ritz? Its a 1.2 liter petrol engine with 85HP.

What types of engines can be turbo-charged.

If it's possible, how would I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following: does the engine currently have 85hp or is that your power goal? **Any engine can be turbo charged.** What matters is what exactly you want the engine to do, your power output goals, and the amount of money you are willing to spend. You may want to fill in the blanks here so this question doesn't get closed as being too broad.

Comment: Yes, you can turbocharge your engine. How is a broad question. Problem is that the 85hp output of your engine will only produce roughly 15% more power at most. And by then you've spend almost half another Suzuki Splash just to get there. Another downside will be that you probably end up by using Gasoline 98 only, which is much more expensive.. If you want to make your car faster, it'll be much cheaper if you put the car on a diet :)

Comment: @paulster, It currently produces around 85bhp , i am just curious as to know if the engine can handle the addition of a turbo.

Comment: @Qwedvit by putting on diet means removing stuff? wont that affect the traction?

Comment: @Anarach - Yes, he means removing weight from the vehicle. What Qwedvit said in general about the 15% gain and cost is spot on.

Comment: @Anarach Yes, removing stuff will reduce the total weight of the vehicle. This will make your car accellerate faster. You shouldn't worry about the traction of your car. Your car has a FF layout (Front engine, FWD) and doesn't have a weight distribution of 50/50, but more like 60/40. You only should worry about traction when your car has lost roughly more than 30% of its weight, which probably wont happen.. Unless ofcourse, you go to extremes..

Comment: Thank you guys, i think i will go with @qwedvit's idea of removing excess weight instead of the turbo thing.. can someone answer my question so that i can close this thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it's a lot cheaper to remove excess weight. If you use this car as a daily drive it's best to keep stuff like a spare tire and jack in your car..

Start with the easy stuff: a lot of people have a lot of stuff in their car that they'll never need. If you want to make the car even more lighter, you could opt to remove the rear seat and plastic panels. Keep in mind that driving with sharp edges on the inside of your car that might hurt you in an accident is illegal in Europe. Remove door trims, carpets and your glove box. Fill the tank of the car only half each time, ..

In case (which I doubt) you want to take this car on trackdays: replace your side and read windows by plexiglass, install a roll cage, lower the center of gravity, keep unsprung weight as low as possible, get to a 50/50 weight distribution, .. It'll be hilarious to see a Suzuki Splash on the track! :)

Remember: less weight = better fuel economy = faster car = more money for racing parts = even faster car!

Comment: Thank you for the answer , definitely not going to take it on a track , have you seen the body roll on that thing?? I feel the reliant robin is much more stable than this thing.. But take 5 people comfortably around the city :-) going remove the carpet and glove box and the stupid vanity spoiler at the back.

Comment: Useless wings are for penguins!