# how to boost petrol engine of a small hatchback

Tags: engine-theory, small-engine

I want to boost 1.2 litre petrol engine of my hatchback.
What are possible ways for it except adding a supercharger?

Comment: Refer to this question http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/turbo-charging-suzuki-splash-ritz

Comment: Without knowing the details of your vehicle, any "bolt-on" power modifications are pure speculation.  Do some research before spending your hard-earned money.  In order to increase the Volumetric Efficiency (VE) of your engine "pump", everything must be balanced to add as much fuel that is needed with any added air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the volume of your engine is fixed and your air pressure is fixed as well your only way of getting more power output is by playing with air temperature, fuel type and controller.
Cold air intake would increase the mass of air that enters the engine and thus produce more pressure during combustion.

A high flow catalyst and exhaust would allow the gases to exit the engine with less resistance (also contributing to the overall power output).

Depending on your engines controller, you could reprogram it for performance though that would require a significant level of experience.

Finally burning a gas with a higher energy density would achieve an increase of power output. Burning methane for example at the **same rate** as petrol should *theoretically*  give you more power as methane has 55,5Mj/Kg while petrol is at 46,4Mj/kg.

Comment: thnQ @PaulB ..that's pretty much what I was looking for!